# df.to_markdown, ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,000'. Disabling number parsing with disable_numparse=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

so this worked perfectly with python 3.9 but I had to downgrade to 3.8 and now this line of code no longer works. I dont understand why it thinks its a float.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': [f"{1000:,d}"], 'col 2': [f"{2000:,d}"]}).to_markdown(index=False)

print(df)
```

**Error Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': [f"{1000:,d}"], 'col 2': [f"{2000:,d}"]}).to_markdown(index=False)
  File "/home/nuke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2340, in to_markdown
    result = tabulate.tabulate(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nuke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 1599, in tabulate
    cols = [
  File "/home/nuke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 1600, in <listcomp>
    [_format(v, ct, fl_fmt, miss_v, has_invisible) for v in c]
  File "/home/nuke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 1600, in <listcomp>
    [_format(v, ct, fl_fmt, miss_v, has_invisible) for v in c]
  File "/home/nuke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 1004, in _format
    return format(float(val), floatfmt)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,000'
```

Comment: do you need commas to format the numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `disable_numparse=True` to `to_markdown()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': [f"{1000:,d}"], 'col 2': [f"{2000:,d}"]}).to_markdown(disable_numparse=True)
df
>>> 
'|    | col 1   | col 2   |\n|:---|:--------|:--------|\n| 0  | 1,000   | 2,000   |'
```

Comment: I want the comma in there as a thousands separator though. It was working perfectly yesterday before I downgraded python versions.

Comment: @drebrb in that case you can set `disable_numparse=True` . See it on the edit